# How to connect correct redis node when get some data use redis command in redis cluster?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

As we known, redis cluster have 16384 hash slots.when redis client connect to redis cluster, how redis client to connect real save data redis node?

Answer (score 0):

The rule is quite simple, redis use `CRC16(key) % 16384` to determine which slot will a key go in. If you want to do everything by yourself, you just need to calculate every key's crc16.

But generally, you don't need to do these by yourself. At the moment, almost every well-known  client, like jedis, predis,StackExchange.Redis , supports the cluster mode.